# Problem with the react-navigation-stack library installation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a problem with the **react-navigation-stack** library installation, *please see the photo*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with the `--force` flag and `--legacy-peer-deps` (this ignores the peer dependencies when installing).

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps @react-navigation/stack --force
```